# On a FAQ how can I style the active q after a user clicks on it with just CSS?

Tags: css, hyperlink

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href='#q1' class='contentlink'>
  Question One?
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href='#q2' class='contentlink'>
  Question Two?
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>


   <h3 id='q1'>
    This is Question One?
    </h3>

    <p>
    This is the answer to question one.
    </p>

    <h3 id='q2'>
    This is Question Two?
    </h3>

    <p>
    This is the answer to question two.
    </p>
```

Without going to jQuery is there a way for me to style a question using some sort of `:active` CSS to do something like make the selection question a different color? I tried doing:

```
<h3 id='q3' class='faq'>This is the question?</h3>
```

Then in my stylesheet:

```
h3.faq:active {
color: yellow;
}
```

But it didn't change the question color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the target pseudo-class. It targets the element for which the id appears after the "#" in the URL.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9MXq3/

Example CSS:

```
h3:target{
background: #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [`:target` pseudoclass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3atarget). Use it like this:

```
h3:target {
    color: yellow;
}
```